# Understanding the proof of "If $V$ is $n$ dimensional vectors space then a set in $V$ with fewer than $n$ vectors does not span $V$ "

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, hamel-basis

In below image author has proved the theorem which states that,

"Let $V$ ve a finite dimensional vector space and $\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$ is basis for $V$ then, "If a set in $V$ has fewer than $n$ vectors then it does not span $V$ "

[image: proof]

**How** author has derived the linear system indicated by an arrow in the picture?

**My attempt**: using equation (4), equation (5) implies,

$k_1(a_{11}w_1+a_{21}w_2+...+a_{m1}w_m)+k_2(a_{12}w_1+a_{22}w_2+...+a_{m2}w_m)+...+...+k_n(a_{1n}w_1+a_{2n}w_2+...+a_{mn}w_m=0$

Which implies,

$(a_{11}k_1+a_{12}k_2+...+a_{1n}k_n)w_1+(a_{21}k_1+a_{22}k_2+...+a_{2n}k_n)w_2+...+(a_{m1}k_1+a_{m2}k_2+...+a_{mn}k_n)w_m=0$

From this to conclude homogeneous linear system indicated by arrow (in pic) we must have $w_1,...,w_m$ must be linearly independent. But, here we doesn't know whether $w_i$'s are linearly independent or not! **So how** author has derived homogeneous linear system in equation indicated by arrow (in pic)

Please help..

Comment: The system of equations implies $(5).$ This is sufficient for getting a contradiction. You do not need equivalence.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc sir question is edited (sorry for typo). How author has obtained the linear system indicated by arrow?(in pic). Further, system of equations in (4) implies (5) but how it is sufficient to get contradiction.

Comment: The homogeneous system of $m$ equations with $n$ unknowns ,where $m<n$  admits a nontrivial solution.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc sir, what I dont get is,  How author has obtained the homogeneous linear system (Indicated by orange colour arrow in pic)? I Already know that homogeneous linear system with more unknown than equations has a nontrivial solution!

Comment: Look at your attempt. If you require that every coefficient of $w_j$ is $0,$ you get that system of equations. I guess the author had this in mind.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc sir, then how every coefficient of $w_j$ is zero? Are $w_j$ are linearly independent?

Comment: The implication is one way  If the coefficient of every $w_j$ is $0,$ i.e. the system indicated by orange arrow is satisfied then $(5)$ is fulfilled. If the orange system has a nonzero solution then $(5)$ is satisfied with some nonzero coefficients, hence $v_j$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc sir, thank you so much for explaining in detail and sorry that I had trouble you by asking/commenting so many times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's solve the following linear system of equations for $x_i'$s, $1\le i\le m$:

$\begin{align}
&a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2+\cdots+a_{1n}x_n=0\\
&a_{21}x_1+a_{22}x_2+\cdots+a_{2n}x_n=0\\
&\cdots\quad\cdots\quad \cdots\quad \cdots \\
 &a_{m1}x_1+a_{m2}x_2+\cdots+a_{mn}x_n=0
\end{align}\tag A$

What property do these $x_i$'s have? It can be shown that they satisfy $x_1v_1+x_2v_2+\cdots+x_nv_n=0\tag B$

Since $m<n$, it follows that $(A)$ has a non-trivial solution i.e., in particular there exist $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ not all zero.
These $x_i$'s must satisfy $(A)$.

But since $v_i$'s are linearly independent, it follows from $(B)$ that $x_i=0$ for all $1\le i\le n$. This contradicts conclusion in last para.

It follows that the assumption that $w_i$'s span $V$ is not correct.

Comment: Sir, I didn't get the part, what property do these $x_i$'s have? It can be shown that they satisfies $x_1v_1+...+x_nv_n=0$ How?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi:  $x_1v_1+...+x_nv_n= x_1 (a_{11}w_1+a_{21}w_2+...+a_{m1}w_m)+...+x_n(a_{1n}w_1+a_{2n}w_2+...+a_{mn}w_m)=\color{blue}{(a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2+...+a_{1n}x_n)}w_1+\color{blue}{(a_{21}x_1+a_{22}x_2+...+a_{2n}x_n)}w_2+\cdots +\color{blue}{(a_{m1}x_1+a_{m2}x_2+...+a_{mn}x_n)}w_m= ?$. Apply $(A)$ for blue colored part.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, for explaining it in details.

Answer (score 1):

If the $\{w_i\}$ are linearly independent then the system of equations you have indicated with an orange arrow necessarily holds in a unique way. If they happen to be linearly dependent, then this may be *one of many* solutions.

In other words, you do not need the $\{w_i\}$ to be linearly independent to reach the system of equations the author is showing, as he is proving that that there exists *some* set of scalars such that some are non-zero and for which (5) still holds. This is why he imposed them to be 0.